# Can't import photoshop work path to flash

Tags: flash, import, path, photoshop

I tried to export Photoshop work path as File->Export->Paths to Illustrator and then import to flash scene both Stage and Library gives nothing. In the import dialog of flash the path is seen as "compound path". But i see no vector drawing neither in library or nor in stage when i say ok in the dialog.

Also to check the file I opened the exported file in Illustrator . When I open the file I can't see the path directly it also shows me like a blank artboard but when hovering over the artboard i can select the path (i don't use too much maybe that's the way Ai is.)

Should i configure the path/file in a way in PS/AI before importing? Or any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to do this a few times myself and it is a bit odd. What I did was open the exported file from photoshop in illustrator and just give the path a stroke colour. Then resave it (it may prompt for you to save in a different/updated ai file format), and then you can import it in flash.

Comment: it solves but anti alisasing problem. I will talk about what i actually need in a new thread. But thank you!